# Troubles to pass an value through Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-state, redux-toolkit

i'm currently working on a project for my portfolio
The project is a basic, website using TheMovieDb APP on React

I'm using redux toolkit to provide DATAS through all my components
this first hooks is working well when i call it in the home components

```
export const GetActualFilms = async () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
api.get(`trending/movie/week?${KEY}&language=fr`)
//SUCCESS
.then((res) => dispatch(setActualFilmsData(res.data.results)))
//ERROR
.catch((error) => console.log(error, "une erreur s'est produite"));
return;};
```

but this other One is crashing my app with an hooks error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9aX6.png)

```
export const GetFilmsDetail = async () => {
    const moviesSearched = useSelector(storedSearchedFilmsData);
    console.log("OK", moviesSearched.searchResults);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    api.get(`search/movie?${KEY}&query=${moviesSearched}&language=fr`)
        //SUCCESS
        .then((res) => console.log(res), dispatch(getSearchedFilmsData(res.data.results)))
        //ERROR
        .catch((error) => console.log(error, "une erreur s'est produite"));
    return;};
```

theses DATAS are used for a search input and passed by a Dispatch

```
export const NavBar = () => {
const [searchedMovies, setSearchedMovies] = useState([]);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(searchedMovies);
    const adjustSearchedMovies = searchedMovies.toString().replace(/ /g, "+");
    dispatch(storedSearchedFilmsData(adjustSearchedMovies));
    GetFilmsDetail();
};
```

Am i doing something wrong ?
Thank you for your reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, you are not allowed to use something like `useDispatch` or `useSelector` outside of a React component body - also not in event handlers etc.

I'd highly encourage you to write a thunk for this logic - maybe give a read to [chapter 5 of the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic) (while chapters 7 and 8 might also be of interest to you here).

Generally, you would write a thunk here and instead of `GetFilmsDetail()` you would call `dispatch(getFilmsDetailThunk())`.

```js
export const getFilmsDetailThunk = async () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const moviesSearched = storedSearchedFilmsData(getState());
    console.log("OK", moviesSearched.searchResults);
    try {
      const res = await api.get(`search/movie?${KEY}&query=${moviesSearched}&language=fr`)
      console.log(res)
      dispatch(getSearchedFilmsData(res.data.results))
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error, "une erreur s'est produite")
    }
}
```

(Also, please use async await intead of then and catch, that will make your code a lot more readable!)

Comment: Thank for your reply, i'll try to convert my code into thoses thunk call,

Comment: Please also read the tutorial - this is a "normal thunk". Nowadays you would usually use a `createAsyncThunk`-generated thunk or use RTK Query. Explaining all that is just a bit much for a single SP answer.

Comment: Thank you for these additional advice, i'm currently trying to read and understand the documentation (i'm french so some words or concept are Harder to get) 
Can i use the createAsyncThunk outside the Slice components an include it inside my fetchApi components ? or is it necessary to be inside the slice components ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: Components are a react thing. They have nothing to do with Slices?

Comment: By components i'm meaning where i wrote these call
I've got one file call index.js into src/api/moviesdatabase an other one into src/reducers/films/index.js
The first one is where i call my API with AXIOS the second one is the reducers/slice
my question is: Does the createAsyncThunk must be inside the reducers/slice components ?
If no can i wrote it inside the API Call Components ?

Comment: It can be in any file. At some point they have to import something from each other. Please don't use the word "component" for file, it will make it tremendously confusing for people trying to communicate with you.